# Object are becoming zombies

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nszombie

I've two variables that are becoming zombies. They are declared like this:

```
@interface SyncPoolController : NSObject {
    NSString *lastUploadQueryTime;
    NSString *lastDownloadQueryTime;
    NSString *pendingPkId;
    NSDate *pendingTimeStamp;
    MediaQueue *currentQueue;
}
```

This call sync data between web server and local database. If a user signs out and then sign in only this 2 variables are becoming zombies. Other variables are okay.

I don't have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Which of the variables does that ? Are you using ARC ?
You probably don't retain them properly, you have local variables, change them to @property (nonatomic, retain). Problem is that your objects are released and you still keep reference to them in your variables.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski > only lastUploadQueryTime and lastDownloadQueryTime does this, other variables are okay.

Comment: Still try to replace those with @property with retain - that should solve the problem. Maybe other variable are retained by something else accidentally - hard to say from what you pasted.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski > Yes I know, but I wanted to know the actual reason because I am using this type of variable declaration in many other places they are not facing any problem but they might so I wanted to know the reason. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Probably other objects are retained by something else and those two are not. But hard to say without actually checking whole code